# How can I prevent YouTube shorts from looping by default?

Tags: video, youtube

I use YouTube app on Android. How can I prevent YouTube short videos from looping by default?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible at all with the official YouTube app. The behavior is the same with the web version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do anything about this currently, but I did send feedback (bottom left of the menu) expressing how dumb this is and that they should have an option not to loop... and also that this option should be default, because why oh why would we want to keep looping?
So I suggest anyone reading this send the same feedback... maybe they will eventually listen.